# Transpose / Pivot rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I am trying to transpose (Pivot?) a table. This is my current setup.
Current Table:

```
ID | Value
1  | 10
1  | 11
1  | 12
1  | 13
1  | 14
2  | 123
3  | 13423
3  | 1134
3  | 1234
```

Seeking the following result:

```
ID | Value01 | Value 02 | Value 03 | Value 04 | Value 05
1  |  10     |  11      |   12     |   13     |  14
2  |  123
3  | 13423   | 1134     | 1234
```

Currently I am trying it with `PIVOT` however I am not completely sure how to `PIVOT` without a "category column" (such as days, or months). Could I use the `ID` column for this?

```
SELECT ID, Value, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4] 
FROM (
      SELECT ID, Value FROM dbo.TABLE
) SourceTable 
PIVOT (
      VALUE FOR ID IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable
```

There is no preset amount of `VALUE`'s for each `ID`. But if it is required to have a known number, 5 values (and thus 5 columns) is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query is close, you are missing the value that you want as the new column names.  My suggestion would be to use `row_number()` which will create an incremented value over each `id`, then you can use the PIVOT function to return the `max(value)` for each of these sequenced values:

```
SELECT ID, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4] 
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, Value, 
    row_number() over(partition by id 
                        order by id) -1  seq
  FROM yourtable
) SourceTable 
PIVOT 
(
  max(VALUE)
  FOR seq IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2fd6/5)

Comment: +1 just note that without an additional column to order by, the location of the values in each column might not match their vertical orientation as shown in the question. Also hooray for staycations! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I added `desc` at `row_number() .. order by ..`

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your comment, there is no need for the orientations to match (pure coincidence in the question); as long as the max 5 values are selected.

Comment: @Ben ok, but it's also important to note that we have no idea what you mean by "max 5" and that if you have 6 values there's no way to guarantee which 5 values will be included. Changing `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY DESC` doesn't change this.

Comment: With "max 5" I mean to select the 5 greatest values out of the list of values. Wouldn't `ORDER BY DESC` enforce this?

Comment: @BenZ. Yes if you want the 5 max values, then you will want to use `order by value desc` in the row number