# How to rotate a table from MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, rotation, transpose

Here is my current table

```
╔══════╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═════╦════╗
║ YEAR ║ A ║ B ║ C ║ ... ║ ZZ ║
╠══════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═════╬════╣
║ 1995 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ ... ║  1 ║
║ 1996 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ ... ║  0 ║
╚══════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═════╩════╝
```

And the table contains around 1000 columns. Now i need to write a code to rotate this table into a more sensible table where i represent values which are denoted as 1. So the resulting table should be like

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ YEAR ║ COLUMN ║ VALUE ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ 1995 ║ A      ║     1 ║
║ 1995 ║ C      ║     1 ║
║ 1995 ║ ZZ     ║     1 ║
║ 1996 ║ A      ║     1 ║
║ 1996 ║ B      ║     1 ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

So by googling bit i started creating a SQL like follows

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_du **???** DEFAULT "";

    DEClARE du_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM date_usage;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN du_cursor;

    get_du: LOOP

        FETCH du_cursor INTO v_du;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_du;
        END IF;

        SHOW v_du; <<---

    END LOOP get_du;

    CLOSE du_cursor; 
END
```

But the problem is i'm not sure how to specify the v_du to be a column and I'm not sure how I'm going to read the column names. And help would be appreciated.

Thankx

Comment: I agree with you. But thats what im trying to do here. But the old table has data which i need to migrate into new structure.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950252/mysql-iterate-through-column-names. You want to iterate through the columns in your table (for each row) and insert the column name and value in a new table. Careful with this new table design - looks very much like a MUCK table.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359345/transposing-dynamic-columns-to-rows

Comment: Where does the data come from in the first place?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931391/transpose-pivot-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Th easiest way is with a bunch of `union all` statements:

```
select year, 'A' as column, A as value from table where A > 0 union all
select year, 'B' as column, B as value from table where B > 0 union all
. . .
select year, 'ZZ' as column, ZZ as value from table where ZZ > 0;
```

I would list the columns using `information_schema.columns` and use Excel to generate the code.

The more efficient way on a large table is use to a `cross join`:

```
select year, col,
       (case when col = 'A' then A
             when col = 'B' then B
             . . .
             when col = 'ZZ' then ZZ
        end) as value
from table t cross join
     (select 'A' as col union all select 'B' union all . . . select 'ZZ') cols
having value > 0;
```

Comment: +1 because this is the right solution to the question. I can't help thinking through there's an issue with your schema design if you have to do queries like this though...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate your data to a new table, do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(`year`, `column`, `value`) SELECT year, 'A', A FROM oldTable WHERE A > 0;
INSERT INTO new_table(`year`, `column`, `value`) SELECT year, 'B', B FROM oldTable WHERE B > 0;
INSERT INTO new_table(`year`, `column`, `value`) SELECT year, 'C', C FROM oldTable WHERE C > 0;
```

repeat for all column names.